# Pull data from API when form loads

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, api, anchor

So I am trying to find the most direct point to do a 'Get' from an API when a page loads. As an example, if in my app I go to "#/somepage", when I click on the link to do so, it also does a get from "http://{{host}}/api/common/trans/claim". That URI contains a single property with no name that looks like " "Bzc5YUL7dNjK6ApxpNK1XB%2bDtTU8cw7xRSGpjZ4XRuE%3d" ". So if I fire or add some listen event to this, what is the best way to store? I know that might be a seperate question, but legitimate here because of how the data is returned. Hopefully I provided and storied my question correctly.

My queries have pointed to things like viewContentLoaded and DOM readiness, etc..., but those seem overkill for this when simply clicking a link an retrieving info from the API.

Keep in mind, this API is local and private and the URI data is only available until after the user is logged in.

Comment: use a `resolve` in router

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not if I follow your question but you can fire the function using the [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive.

To store the return value you could set it to the `$scope` of your controller or save it to a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) if you'd like to share the data across controllers.

Comment: I know about ng-click, but do not see how this would work in this circumstance. What did you not follow on my question? So my questions is such that, if using ng-click, how does that look since all I know initially is the URI?

Comment: Re-reading your answer, am wondering how I would even apply ng-click to something like: <a ng-href="{{ ppt.Globals.hasDebitCard ? '#/claimEnter' : '#/claimSub' }}"> where only one side needs to be listened too.